# WCF basicHttpBinding with userName and password from a WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, basichttpbinding

I have read some questions here in SO and some linked tutorial.

I have done all the stuff, but I have a problem... the authentication doesn't work.. it gives an exception only if I send a random username, without regarding about the password.

I think, maybe, because the validator I have written it's never called ( I have breakpointed it)... but why?

This is my app.confing of the wcf:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  <add key="userName" value="piero"/>
  <add key="password" value="piero"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<!-- Quando si distribuisce il progetto della libreria di servizi, è necessario aggiungere il contenuto del file di configurazione al file 
app.config dell'host. System.Configuration non supporta i file di configurazione delle librerie. -->
<system.serviceModel>
  <!--<standardEndpoints/>-->
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="usernameHttps">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="calc.CalcService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="base" contract="calc.ICalcService"  >
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"  />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="" name="web" contract="calc.ICalcService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/calc/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>


      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="customBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
          userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="calc.CustomPass, calc"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>

    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"  />
  </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and this is the config of the calling wpf app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <startup> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
      <system.serviceModel>
          <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
                  <!--<binding name="base" />-->
                <binding name="base">
                  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </basicHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
              <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/calc/"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="base" contract="calcTest.ICalcService"
                  name="base" />
          </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="userName" value="aaa"/>
      <add key="password" value="bbb"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

and this is the validator of the wcf:

```
public class CustomPass : UserNamePasswordValidator //System.IdentityModel.dll
{
    private const string USERNAME_ELEMENT_NAME = "userName";

    private const string PASSWORD_ELEMENT_NAME = "password";

    private const string FAULT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "UserName or Password is incorrect!";

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        //Guarder.Guard.ArgumentNotNull(userName).ArgumentNotNull(password);
        var validateUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[USERNAME_ELEMENT_NAME];
        var validatePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[PASSWORD_ELEMENT_NAME];
        var validateCondition = userName.Equals(validateUserName) && password.Equals(validatePassword);
        if (!validateCondition)
        {
            throw new FaultException(FAULT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

So:

- the wcf service starts correctly;
- the wpf app calls it  (basicHttpBinding) and uses it but:

  1. if there is no username, it gets error from wcf (this is ok, I think)
  2. the wcf service accepts ALL username, not only the one I have set in the     validator
  3. the password is useless, I can send anything, but only the username seems

to be read in some way but the wcf

How can I use my validator? Why it doesn't start?

I call the wcf in this way (any errors here?):

```
private void Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var n1 = this.opOne.Text.ToString();
    var n2 = this.opTwo.Text.ToString();
    var calc = new calcTest.CalcServiceClient();
    calc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "piero";
    calc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "piero";
    this.res.Text = calc.Add(n1, n2);
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I have now added this: behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior" in the basicHttpBinding endpoint, it says it is not a valid value, but it is the name of my custom behavior...

Comment: it is not even an exception.. in the visual studio editor, it is blu underlined.. and the message says: "The attribute behaviorConfiguration is not valid. The value customBehavior is not valid for the endpointBehaviorConfigurationType data type"

Comment: Ok, ok, this is fixed.. but it still doesn't call my validator!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you just debug the "Service.Open()" - Method?

There you will see if your CustomBehavior is added to the Behavios of the service. You have to invoke the Behavior-Methods, and call the CustomPasswordValidator.

So you need to write a CustomBehavior wich extends the ServiceBehavior, and then invoke one of the four Methods (Valdate, AddBindingParameters, etc...)
You need to find out, where the PasswordValidator is called.

I think it is in the SecurityBindingElement of the BindingElementCollection of your binding of the service (wow what a sentence). Next you must add the CustomBehavior (app.config or dirctly in the code). Maby you need to cast your binding to a CustomBinding to be able to change the elements of the SecurityBindingelement.

I hope this will help you to solve your problem with the CustomPasswordValidator.